# Is there something similar to Oracle's SQL%FOUND in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Did there have a statement like Oracle's `SQL%FOUND` in PostgreSQL? While, I want to judge the value if the SQL statement update or not.

The code just like below in PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
SELECT A,B
FROM TABLE_NAME_2
WHERE A>2;
IF SQL%FOUND THEN   ---error in PostgreSQL
C = 1;
ELSE 
C = 0;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PostgreSQL has `FOUND` statement. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS).

Example:

```
SELECT * INTO myrec FROM emp WHERE empname = myname;
IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'employee % not found', myname;
END IF;
```

Comment: Another option would be to use `GET DIAGNOSTICS affected_rows = ROW_COUNT;`

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name! --